# How to add Element Values to An Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a driver which is testing whether or not values of the provided bank account is added to the accounts array.

Here is the driver:

```
public class CustomerTest {

    private static int customerCounter = 0;

    public static boolean test1(){
        System.out.println("Test1: create a customer");
        Customer c = new Customer("John", "Green");
        customerCounter++;
        return c.getName().equals("John Green") && customerCounter == c.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static boolean test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2: create two customers");
        Customer c1 = new Customer("John", "Green");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("Mike", "Red");
        customerCounter += 2;
        return c1.getName().equals("John Green") && (customerCounter - 1) == c1.getCustomerID()
            && c2.getName().equals("Mike Red") && (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID();
    }

    public static boolean test4() {
        System.out.println("Test4: copy a customer");
        Customer c1 = new Customer("John", "Green");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("Mike", "Red");
        c1.copy(c2);
        customerCounter += 2;
        return c1.getName().equals("Mike Red") && (customerCounter) == c1.getCustomerID()
            && c2.getName().equals("Mike Red") && (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID()
            && c1 != c2;
    }

    public static boolean test5() {
        System.out.println("Test5: add an account to a customer.");
        BankAccount b = new BankAccount();
        Customer c1 = new Customer("John", "Green");
        customerCounter ++;
        if (!c1.addAccount(b))
            return false;

        return c1.toString().equals("John Green, " + c1.getCustomerID() + "\n" + b.toString() + "\n");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        //System.out.print("Test 1: ");
        result = test1() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);

        //System.out.print("Test 2: ");
        result = test2() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);

        //System.out.print("Test 4: ");
        result = test4() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);

        //System.out.print("Test 5: ");
        result = test5() ? "pass." : "failed.";
        System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

Here is what I've written so far. The addAccounts method is what I am using to add in values to the accounts array. The method returns false if there already exists an account in accounts with the same account number or if the array is full.

```
public class Customer {

    public static final int MAX_ACCOUNTS = 5;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int customerID;
    private BankAccount[] accounts;
    private int numAccounts;
    private static int nextCustomerID = 1;


    //default constructor
    public Customer() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        customerID = nextCustomerID;
        accounts = null;
        numAccounts = 0;
        nextCustomerID++;
    }

    public Customer (String first, String last)
    {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.customerID = nextCustomerID;
        nextCustomerID++;
    }    

    public void copy (Customer copyFrom) {
        this.firstName = copyFrom.firstName;
        this.lastName = copyFrom.lastName;
        this.customerID = copyFrom.customerID;
        this.accounts = copyFrom.accounts;
        this.numAccounts = copyFrom.numAccounts;
    }

    public boolean addAccount (BankAccount newAccount[])
    {
        if (numAccounts < 5){
        int BankAccountLen = newAccount.length;

        BankAccount[] newBank = new BankAccount[BankAccountLen];

        System.arraycopy(newAccount, 0, newBank, 0, BankAccountLen);
         return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }


    }

    public BankAccount[] getAccounts ()
    {
        return accounts;

    }

    public String getFirst(){
        return firstName;

    }

    public String getLast(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return String.format("%s %s", getFirst(), getLast());

    }

    public int getCustomerID ()
    {
        return customerID;

    } 
    public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%s %s %s", getFirst(), getLast(), getCustomerID());
    return String.format("%d",numAccounts);


}

}
```

test5 will show failed when it should show pass if the add to the accounts array was successful. But it is throwing an exception as well:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method addAccount(BankAccount[]) in the type Customer is not applicable for the arguments (BankAccount)

    at CustomerTest.test5(CustomerTest.java:44)
    at CustomerTest.main(CustomerTest.java:192)
```

Comment: return newBank; is choking because the function expects to return a boolean.

Comment: @MiloStaKic Just for my curiosity: why don't You use one of the existing unit test frameworks instead of writing your own?

Comment: @JeremyKahan my mistake. I have changed it to return true and false.

Comment: @MiloStaKic Please post an Answer and accept it to close this Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque I still am not adding anything to the array

Comment: When you get to the addAccount method… Why are you creating a new BankAccount? This will be destroyed as soon as addAccount exits. Are you sure you don’t want to add the new account to accounts.add(newAccount)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things you should correct. Also, your way of adding elements to an array seems really weird to me. I would suggest you to use a better method. You can also use an array list if that's allowed.

First, you need to initialize the `accounts` array in the two constructors:

```
//default constructor
public Customer() {
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    customerID = nextCustomerID;
    accounts = new BankAccount[MAX_ACCOUNTS];
    numAccounts = 0;
    nextCustomerID++;
}

public Customer (String first, String last)
{
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.customerID = nextCustomerID;
    nextCustomerID++;
    accounts = new BankAccount[MAX_ACCOUNTS];
}
```

Now change `addAccount` to this.

```
public boolean addAccount (BankAccount newAccount)
{
    if (numAccounts < MAX_ACCOUNTS || Arrays.asList(accounts).contains(newAccount)){
        accounts[numAccount] = newAccount;
        numAccounts++;
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are allowed to use an `ArrayList`, then the code would be much simpler!

First declare `accounts` as an array list:

```
private ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts;
```

And initailize it in the constructors:

```
//default constructor
public Customer() {
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    customerID = nextCustomerID;
    accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    numAccounts = 0;
    nextCustomerID++;
}

public Customer (String first, String last)
{
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.customerID = nextCustomerID;
    nextCustomerID++;
    accounts = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

You also need to change the `getAccounts` method to this:

```
public ArrayList<BankAccount> getAccounts ()
{
    return accounts;

}
```

Because of this change, you might have to change your test to comply with the new `ArrayList<BankAccount>` return type.

As you can see, the `addAccount` method becomes very simple:

```
public boolean addAccount (BankAccount newAccount)
{
    if (accounts.size() < MAX_ACCOUNTS || accounts.contains(newAccount)){
        accounts.add(newAccount);
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also delete the `numAccounts` variable all together!

Your `toString` method should look like this if you stuck with the array approach (this is the best solution I can think of. I'm bad at dealing with arrays. This is certainly not the best solution out there.):

```
return String.format("%s %s %s", getFirst(), getLast(), getCustomerID()) + 
    Arrays.toString(Arrays.asList(accounts).stream().filter(x -> x != null).toArray());
```

If you use the array list approach, it's much simpler:

```
return String.format("%s %s %s", getFirst(), getLast(), getCustomerID()) + 
    accounts.toString();
```

Comment: what are the non-null entries in the accounts array?

Comment: I didn't mention anything about non-null entries. What do you mean? @MiloStaKic

Comment: I need to return them in the toString method, which I forgot to add in my original question, in order for the test5 to work.

Comment: If you sticked to using an array, your original `toString` method should work fine. If you're using the array list method, all of the entries are non-null. Or did you not write a `toString` method and wanted to get help with that? @MiloStaKic

Comment: 'public String toString()
    {
     return String.format("%s %s %s", getFirst(), getLast(), getCustomerID());
     return String.format("%d",accounts);


    }'  the first line is fine, the second should contain the non null entries. I'm not sure if that is accounts

Comment: I have added in the method to the original question. I am not sure about the second return value

Comment: your answer makes sense to me, but test5 still fails and I have no idea why. There is no more errors or exception, it just fails.

Comment: Ah I see. My code does return the non null values, but it's apparently in a different format from the required value. Maybe post another  question? Because this discussion is starting to become off topic @MiloStaKic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455219/method-not-passing-driver-test

Comment: It is also failing using the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

## Poor Question

You have *way* too much code posted here. We expect a minimal example of code, the least needed to show your issue. In doing that, you'd probably answer the question yourself.

By the way, `BankAccountLen` should be `bankAccountLen` to follow Java naming conventions.

## Error message tells all

Read your error message, as it tells you the exact problem. You declared the method as taking an array of BankAccount objects, yet you pass a BankAccount object directly.

A box of cookies is not a cookie, and a car full of clowns is not itself a clown. Don't conflate a collection of things with the things inside. You must be clear and precise when declaring your arguments to a method.

I presume your method declaration was a typo mistake, and you did intend to pass a single BankAccount object rather than a collection of BankAccount objects. So delete the `[]` from your method declaration.

```
public boolean addAccount ( BankAccount newAccount ) { …
```

## `List`

Tip: Use a `List` like `ArrayList` for an ordered collection that can grow, rather than array.

Another tip: Consider using a unit testing framework like JUnit rather than roll-your-own.

Comment: "you do not follow Java naming conventions." Really? I think the OP followed naming conventions quite well, PascalCase for classes, camelCase for methods and variables and all caps for constants. Except for the `c1` and `b`s in test class. But I mean, they are just dummy variables used for testing...

Comment: @Sweeper Reworded to be specific.